# Model predicting when success is binary

Tags: machine-learning

Beginner question as I'm learning ML - most models seem to be designed to predict a final value, however I've had multiple models  where the outcome is binary (success/fail).

Is there a better way to develop models other than just rounding predictions to Int?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ML models, the best one to use depends on the problem and the data.

There are 3 main different problems in ML:

- **Supervised Learning** (Algorithms are trained using labeled data)
- **Unsupervised Learning** (Algorithms are used against data which is not labeled)
- **Reinforcement Learning** (Doesn't need labelled input/output, exploration/explotation )

You are talking about Supervised Learning, where we have either **regression** algorithms or **classification problems**, both share the same concept of utilising known datasets (referred to as training datasets) to make predictions.

[image: ML chart]

When we have a classification problem where the output is binary, we are talking about **binary classification** problems. However, when we have more than 2 expected outputs, we are talking about **multiclass clasification** problems.

There are many algorithms/models to solve these problems, for example:
Naive Bayes, SVM, Random Forest, Gradient Boosting..

Here you can learn more about these algorithms:
[Common ML Algorithms](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/common-machine-learning-algorithms/)